# How to vertically align to the lists?

Tags: css

I'm trying to align vertically to the text of the lists but couldn't success.

```
li{
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use display:flex; for younger browsers if you do not want to edit your HTML : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/8/)**

```
ul{
    width: 50%;
}
li{
    height: 100px;
    display:block;/* or else as fall back to erase bullets */
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If browser doesn't understand `display:flex;` , content will be standing on top.

---

If you want to wrap text, content of li in an extra container, then `display:table`/`table-cell` comes avalaible: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/10/)**  or other techniques with pseudo and `vertical-align`+`inline-block;` : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/11/)**

Comment: you are master of `pseudo-elements`  :)

Comment: @KheemaPandey , they exist, are usefull and do not damage the markup so i like to talk about them :) Someone , Alek, talked about the line height in another answer, so i guess we have covered most of clean solutions

Comment: I've seen many of examples; you just made using `pseudo-elements`

Comment: ah okay,  hope you like it and get ideas

Comment: surely it will help me in near future.

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height: 100px;`

```
    li{
        height: 100px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px solid red;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
```

Second approach:

**html**

```
<ul>

    <li>
        <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </span>
    </li>
     <li>
        <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </span>
     </li>
     <li>   
        <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul{
    width: 50%;
}
li{
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

span{
  display: table-cell;  
  height: 100px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/17/)

Comment: did you try? line-height damage the display.

Comment: Which one? if you refer to this http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/1/, than it doesn't work, it breaks the display of the text.

Comment: Hmm yeah it depends on resolutions.

Comment: Check my second approach please.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain?

Comment: `display:table-cell` is okay but why wrapping `<li>` inside a `span` tag?

Comment: It's fine to use a <span> and a <br> in a <li>.

Comment: li can hold any block elements, that is right, but can only be child of ul or ol, the markup proposed here is not valid. span should be wrapped by li and not the other way round. You should fix your answer before getting downvotes :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Fixed according your comment:) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aHU8z/12/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
    <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
    <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
    <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul{
    width: 50%;
    display:table;
}
li{ 
    display:table-row;
    list-style:none;
    height: 100px;
  }

li > span{

    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;

}
```

Comment: I was going to ask you that. You should have stated before that the length/height of the text will vary

Answer (score 0):

How about using this solution. Instead of giving a `height` giving some  `padding` on `li`.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/niceneju/1/edit)**.

```
ul{
    width: 50%;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:20px 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: good solution, though I've to use some fixed height for some reason.

Comment: then follow what @GCyrillus suggested. His answer is best.

Answer (score 0):

use `display table-cell`

```
li {
       display:table-cell;
       height: 100px;
       border: 1px solid red;
       vertical-align:middle;
       width:500px; /*example width as width wont work with table-cell*/
}
```